# Calculate Json Size and set it as a property in Serialized C# Object

Tags: c#, annotations, json.net, jsonserializer

I have an API

```
createStudentRecord([FromBody] StudentRecord studentRecord)
{
// some piece of code.
}
```

which is taking an object and there is a json serializer in my code to convert the json supplied in the API call to the StudentRecord object. **I want to find out the size of each json record during the time of ingestion**

```
public class StudentRecord
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "StudentName")]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MarksPerSubject")]
        public IDictionary<string, List<Integer>> MarksPerSubject { get; set; }
    }
```

**Is it possible to modify/extend Newtonsoft.Json libraries so that I can have the size of the record available to me in the StudentRecord object of createStudentRecord API ?**

Comment: Size in terms of number of characters, or in terms of bytes?  Do you want to include whitespace formatting in the size?

Comment: size in terms of bytes is what i am looking for and including white-space formatting

Comment: I don't think this can be done at the Json.NET level.  The Json.NET parser `JsonTextReader` works with character streams coming from a supplied `StreamReader`.  It's the `StreamReader` that handles the decoding of bytes to characters (as a Utf8 stream, or whatever other encoding was actually used) so Json.NET never seems the underlying byte stream.  You might be able to track this at the [tag:asp.net] level, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: You also might be able to do something with [tag:system.text.json] because it parses Utf8 byte streams directly without using an encoder.  `Utf8JsonReader` has a [`BytesConsumed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.bytesconsumed?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader_BytesConsumed) property that might provide what you need...